# nth Child selector is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

nth Child selector is not working. My code segment is as follows,

```
$(this).parent().parent().("tr :nth-child(" + colNo + ")" ).text(value);
```

Here, colNo and value is a variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is html dom nodes structure??

Comment: Without having any context: `tr` is a row, but `colNo` supposedly means column? Are you sure you haven't forgotten a space inbetween: `tr :nth-child(`?

Comment: syntax is wrong here...`rent().("t` ???

Comment: HTML DOM node structure :
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: @blgt, Yes, there is a space between tr and :nth-child(

Comment: You can use like $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(colNo).text(value);

Comment: @kaizzy Can i put it as answer? will u accept it?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Yes, Definitely, I will accept it. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(colNo).text(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the colNo row of the table and then changing it's text, which is probably not what you want.
You may want to change the text of the cells inside the row or actually select a column of cells using this alternatives:

```
   $(this).parent().parent().("tr:nth-child(" + colNo + ") td" ).text(value);
   $(this).parent().parent().("tr td:nth-child(" + colNo + ")" ).text(value);
```

Comment: I have reached a particular row and want to change the nth column of it. So, second option is suitable for me. But, it is not working. Even `alert($(this).parent().parent().("td :nth-child(" + colNo + ")" ).html());` is now working. :(